# How can I configure Midnight Commander to execute "open %file_name%" command every time when I press Enter

Tags: macos

Can I somehow configure Midnight Commander to execute "open %file_name%" command every time when I press Enter? If so, how can I do it?

Comment: Well, you´ve asked and I answered  - no reply is rude. If my answer fits please accept the answer below or give me more details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could edit the extension file (*Menu → Command → Edit extension file*). I couldn´t test it on OSX but this should work:

```
regex/\.(.*)$
    Open=(open %f &)
```

Answer (score 3):

Improvement on UsersUser's answer: Use `%s` instead of `%f` to be able to open multiple files at once. Refer to the explanation inside the mc.ext config file.

Excerpt:

> %s -> "selected files", i.e. space separated list of tagged files if
>   any
>         or name of the current file.

Ergo:

```
regex/\.(.*)$
        Open=(open %s &)
```

Answer (score 1):

Updating this for 2023, the regex line is now unnecessary, thus only this should be added for images and some other files (PDF for example):

```
Open=(open %s &)
```